# Laptop ASUS K55VJ high temperature on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, laptop, asus, temperature

I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 instead of Windows, but temperature of CPU is raised on 50% on Windows it was 35-40 degrees, and on Ubuntu it become 55-60 degrees in relaxed working.

I checked temperature through terminal.

Computer(ASUS K55VJ) parameters is:

```
Intel® Core™ i5 3210M Processor
Intel® Chief River Chipset HM76
NVIDIA® GeForce® GT 635M with 2GB DDR3 VRAM
Power adapter: Output :
19 V DC, 4.74 A, 90 W ((Dual Core)) , 120 W ((Quad Core))
Input :
100 -240 V AC, 50/60 Hz universal
```

Anyone had problems with this laptop temperature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing [TLP](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html):

```
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

It works well out the box and should also help with battery life. It works well for me on my Dell XPS 15.

There are other tools you can try if that doesn't work for you, check out [this comprehensive article on itsfoss.com](https://itsfoss.com/reduce-overheating-laptops-linux/)

Comment: Thank you I already installed it, it helped. I will mark your question.

Answer (score 0):

Trouble on the Gnome side, bad optimization, my friend who uses kubuntu gived me advice to install kde, and it helped kde gives me 45-50 degrees on CPU. Not perfect but better.

Not sure my answer is right so i leave it unmarked.